# Send in-memory file in Express.js

Tags: node.js

I have generated a zip file object using "ADM-ZIP", yet I don't find a way to send it to client from express. I only see a method `res.sendFile(path, [options], [fn])` which requires a local file path. 
I don't think it is a good practice to write the zip file object to local disk then send it, so can I just send this in-memory file and let it recycled after send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe streams/buffers to res:

```
yourZipData.pipe(res);
```

You will probably want to set the correct header first:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/zip'
});
```